# Is a ring homomorphism a homomorphism of multiplicative groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-homomorphism

By definition, a ring homomorphism is a homomorphism of additive groups that also *" respects" the multiplication operations in the two rings.*

From the last statement, does this mean that a ring homomorphism is also a homomorphism of multiplicative groups? Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: A ring is not a multiplicative group ($0$ never has an inverse, for one). It is, however, a multiplicative *semigroup*, and the ring homomorphism  must be a semigroup homomorphism for that structure.. That is, $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$ for all $x$ and $y$.

Comment: (well, the trivial ring is a multiplicative group... but that’s the only one)

Comment: It is actually a *monoid* homomorphism for the multiplicative structure.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: Only if you are working in the category of rings with unity.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Of course.